# morris.js and asmx wrbservice

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asmx, morris.js

i have some troubles using morris.js with asp.net webservice
here my js code :

```
    function Graph() {
        var dd = JSON.stringify({ "panum": pnum, "rubnum" : rnum });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "MyService.asmx/Getchartdata",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: dd,
            success: function (result) {
                dd = result; // also tried data.d
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });

        return dd;
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {

        Morris.Line({
            element: 'area-example',
            data: Graph(),
            xkey: 'DAT',
            ykeys: ['VAL'],
            labels: ['VAL'],
            smooth: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here the code of my webservice method

```
   public class ChartPointClass
{
    public string DAT { get; set; }

    public string VAL { get; set; }
}


[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string Getchartdata(int panum, int rubnum)
{
    string result = "";

    using (Entities me = ContextFactory.ObtainContext())
    {


        var q = from n in me.VISRUBs.Where(a => a.RUBNUM == rubnum && a.VISANA.VISITE.PANUM == panum)
                .OrderBy(a => a.VISANA.VISITE.DATEVIS).ToList()

                select new ChartPointClass()
                {
                    DAT = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", (DateTime)n.VISANA.VISITE.DATEVIS.Value),
                    VAL = n.VALEUR
                };



        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        result = serializer.Serialize(q.ToList());
        return result;
    }

}
```

i have also checked that the data returned from my web service are in this form

```
<string xmlns="http://MyWebsite.net/WebServices">
```

[{"DAT":"12/01/2015","VAL":"0.92"},{"DAT":"22/01/2015","VAL":"1.00"},{"DAT":"15/02/2015","VAL":"0.98"}]

the problem is that an internal server error with this setup and an error in the console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined .

any idea what i am missing please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    function CreateGraph(dt) {

        Morris.Line({
            element: 'area-example',
            data: $.parseJSON(dt),
            xkey: 'DAT',
            ykeys: ['VAL'],
            labels: ['VAL'],
            smooth: false,
            parseTime: false
        });
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {


        var dd = JSON.stringify({ "panum": 5211, "rubnum": 22});
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "MyWebService.asmx/Getchartdata",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: dd,
            success: function (result) {

                CreateGraph(result.d)
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });

    });
```

the **parsetime** parameter was a key element .